# Pipemodelling with Curves and T-Junction

Tags: modeling, python, mesh, bezier-curves, topology

[image]Is it not possible to bevel a pipe out of a 90° curve with t-junction? Any work arround? It must be easy to control. Any Ideas?

Comment: A curve vertex can't be connected to more than 2 vertices if it's your question

Comment: i just want to bevel a curve with multiple crossing. i need them for a visual connection line and want to keep them non destructive. a curve with just two open endpoints works fine. but with more ends it wont work

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible with a simple curve setup, see @moonboots comment. Maybe some crazy NURBS setup that I can't picture.
Here are your options:
1.
[image]

Skin Modifier on a mesh without any faces. It does support t-joints, however you have little control over how exactly the connections look like. Still, it is easy to change later on.

2. 

Edit -> Preferences -> Extra mesh objects. 
This will allow you to add pipe joints. Even though this is considered a destructive workflow, I would prefer it. If you keep the connections clean, it should be easy enough to re-arrange the construct later on (make sure to store a to-scale copy of each component (mesh object) you are using, for later modification) It will look much cleaner than the curve bevel or skin modifier.

3.
Use the boolean modifier with curve objects (or meshes). Be aware, it's not the most reliable modifier in the stack, so there is a chance that it breaks somewhere along the way.